# What size gasket to use on tub overflow drain?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, overflow

I have an old tub and the gasket for the overflow had broken down to nothing. I bought a new foam rubber gasket at Ace, but it's tapered more than the tub is slanted. When I fit the gasket in, there was a big gap at the top, and the gasket pushes the pipe so far from the tub that the screws can't reach the threads to compress it to fit.

There is about a 1/4" gap at the bottom and a 3/16" gap at the top. The gasket is 9/16" to 3/16"

Should I get longer screws? Are there more narrow gaskets? Any tips for forcing the pipe closed to engage the screws?

Here's a photo. The edges of the drain hole are really corroded. Should I try to fix that somehow while I'm here? I don't want to open up a can of worms, but I'm worried about it leaking again in the near future.

[image]

Comment: Go to a place that has a wider range of gaskets and select something better. Without the maker's name of the tub there is not much else, and even then they may not be around any more.

Comment: Picture(s) would be great. I think I know how to answer, but need to see it to be sure.

Comment: Added photo, I also called a plumbing supply store in the area and they said they have thinner gaskets. Anything specific I should be looking at when I'm there?

Comment: Something thinner and tapered less. You might have to buy a few gaskets and see which one fits the best. (That's the "charm" of working on old houses...) You might hit up auto parts stores or farm supply stores too--they usually have all kinds of gaskets around. You may have to make a gasket to fit properly. If you don't find one that works, check back here for more suggestions, etc.

Comment: If I cannot find the correct one I use neoprene or silicon sheet and cut one out I have sheets 1/8 to 1/2” thick. Normally the cover has an opening and the seal is between the tub and the flange. If you totally seal the cover it won’t work as an overflow.